# problem with UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone

```
-(IBAction)changeSegmentDistance:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{
//  refineDistance=sender;

    switch ([refineDistance selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
            valueString=5;
            NSLog(@"value String %d",valueString);  
            break;
        case 1:
            valueString=10;
            NSLog(@"value Stringaaaa %d",valueString);  

        case 2:
            valueString=15;
            NSLog(@"value String %d",valueString);
            break;
        case 3:
            valueString=16;
            NSLog(@"value String %d",valueString);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

When i running application and printing on Console

using NSLog...

when i select 0 its printing 5...
when i selected 1 its printing 10 and 15
when i selected 2 its printing 15
when i selected 3 its printed 16..

I dont know why its printing 10 and 15 when i selected 2nd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a "`break;`" at the end of your "`case 1`" statement block. As such, execution is continuting into the next case statement.

Comment: @kiran kumar - No problems - it happens to us all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `break` for `case 1`.